# the res directory does't contain a layout directory and on adding an android resource directory there is no option for ConstrainLayout and shows error

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

when I started to create the android resource directory for layout in res directory there was no option for ConstraintLayout. I chose the option for LinearLayout and then tried to convert the Linear Layout to ConstraintLayout by adding it to the component tree, but then this error came up

This operation requires the library androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:+.  Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found. Version incompatibility between: - androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.3.0@aar and: - androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.0@aar  With the dependency: - org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:[1.6.4,1.6.5) versus: - org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:[1.5.2,1.5.3)  The project may not compile after adding this library. Would you like to add it anyway?

i only tried reinstalling the program and i tried using chatgpt which told me to update the dependencies. But i preferred to ask the question here. please help.